# How do I avoid unintentional reshaping of an image in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform in excel which is used to "log in" certain usertypes.

Under the control box and the textbox, I have an "img" that I use as a button. I do this instead of a "normal" button because it looks better.

The issue is that when I press the login button the "img" reshapes (see 2nd screenshot).
This does not happen on my computer, but rather if it's used on a different computer.

I have no code whatsoever that reshapes the button so after scouring the web for some answers I believe it has something to do with the DPI of the different computers/monitors.

Is there a way to solve this so that the "img" doesn't reshape?

Noted behavior: When I press the button (img) the button reshapes and the macro is NOT run. Then, when I press the small button, the macro runs.

Tried solutions that do not work:

1. button.width = button.width
2. button.width = 150
3. button.widht = password.width

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about `Image1.AutoSize = False` and `Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizemodeZoom`; alternatively you could integrate the image into a Frame as picture. - Would appriciate feedback if you want this comment to be formulated as answer :-) @Nick

Comment: Thank you for some ideas. With the first suggestion, I assume you want me to change the properties of the "img" (=no code). The autosize was equal to 'True' so I will test if it helps changing this to 'False'. The 'PictureSizeMode' was already set to 'fmPictureSizemodeZoom". 

I currently don't have access to the other computer so I will update you once I have tested it. 

I'm not sure if I understand you second suggestion, Do you mean (1) to simply move the "img" into a frame? or (2) to actually use a 'frame' instead of 'img'? (and use frame1.picture to add the JPEG?) @T.M.

Comment: Bit of both: You have the picture property to include the image to a frame (and take care to zoom the included image in the frame's props; use the Frame1_Click() event for further action @Nick

Comment: Okay, I've only been able to test the first suggestion, (Image1.AutoSize = False). 
This did not work. When I pressed the button, it kind of disappeard. 
I believe that the width didn't change, but the height changed so much that the image was now below the boundries of my userform.  @T.M.
I'll give another update once I've tested the frame suggestion.

Comment: @T.M., the "frame suggestion" did unfortunately not work. However I did manage to find a solution that works for me. I inserted a transparent label over the button, which when pressed, have the exact same code as if you were to press the button. This allowed me to run the exact same code, no difference in the graphics and the button did not resize (I never actually click the button since the label is in front of it.)

Comment: I believe I was able to do this because the button/image did not resize until I actually pressed it, which i'm now no longer doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution that worked for my case was:

Inserting a transparent label above the image. Meaning that I actually press the label instead of the Image.

I moved the code so that it activates on the label_click instead of the Image_click.